# How to post a data in Angular?

Tags: php, angularjs

I try to make a post query to save my array in database. server side is PHP. My angular part:

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "addOrder.php",
            data: myJsonedArray,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });
```

Angular make a post query to addData.php, but in php file my command

```
print_r($_POST); or print_r($_REQUEST);
```

give me empty Array();

How to fix it? Thanks

**UPDATE:** 
if I try this example in jquery - I have he same result - empty array, but if I try with "test_var" - example works well:

```
$.post("addOrder.php", { "test_var": da }, function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

How to make the same result? I've tried

```
 $http({

            method: 'POST',
            url: "addOrder.php",
            data: { "test_var": da },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });
```

but no result (

Comment: What about `file_get_contents('php://input')`? Like `print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true));`

Comment: have a close look at : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http#methods_post, try to debug from Angular side if it was success or fail. Inspect using firebug, see if your data is actually sent or not when a request happens

Comment: I Was going to point out setting the header; but it likes you're already doing that.  Have you used a 'network sniffer' to examine the request?  I write up a lengthy blog post about this on in relation to ColdFusion: http://www.jeffryhouser.com/index.cfm/2013/10/1/Calling-a-ColdFusion-CFC-from-AngularJS and also read this post which is PHP Specific: http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/

Comment: Open the browser's debugger & see what gets sent to the server. In Chrome, look in the Network tab

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this helps: http://www.cleverweb.nl/javascript/a-simple-search-with-angularjs-and-php/

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$objData = json_decode($data);
```

Also, I find $resource much easier to use...